# Write a LINQ query for 2 tables

Tags: c#, linq

I have got 2 tables, `Student` and `CourseTaken`. I need to write a `LINQ` code that displays all `CourseTaken`, that has Active student status set as `true`.

I wrote part of the LINQ statement that will display all CourseTaken for a particular Id. How can I further filter it by showing the `coursetaken` for `Active` students? (`S_ID` in `CourseTaken` contains the student Id.)

```
List<CourseTaken> courseTakenList =
    await dbcont
        .CourseTaken
        .Where(c => c.CId == courseId)
        .ToListAsync();


public class Student
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public string School;
    public bool Active;
}

public class CourseTaken
{

    public int CId;
    public string CourseName;
    public int S_Id;
}
```

Note: I need to use LINQ and Lambda expressions.

Comment: Please be specific, what is your intended output as the wording is a little hard to understand

Comment: Intended output is to display all CourseTaken where the Student is in Active status. I will have to join 2 tables i guess.

Comment: So do you want, a list of courses, where it has active students?

Comment: @TheGeneral Yes, that will be the required output.

Answer (score 3):

This will give you a list of all courses that has an active student, this assumes you have a navigation property from courses to student called `Students`

```
var result = dbcont.CourseTaken.Where(c => c.Students.Any(s => s.Active));
```

If this is not correct, i think you need to explain your structure better, whether this is Entity framework and you have the appropriate navigation property, and some example data

**Update**

> No, I don't have navigation properties in place. Is there another way
>   I could get this done ?

Well you probably should, as you are going to have to query the database twice now.

```
var ids = dbcont.Students.Where(s => s.Active)
                         .Select(x => x.id)
                         .ToList();

var result = dbcont.CourseTaken.Where(c => ids.Contains(c.S_Id));
```

Lastly, take a look at a few entity framework tutorials, your column naming is a little weird, and you really need to hook this up in the spirit of EF. with navigation properties

Comment: No, I don't have navigation properties in place. Is there another way I could get this done ?

Comment: Maybe a `.ToLookup` would be better in this case?

Comment: @JohanP do you mean `ToLookup` on the courses by student Id?

Comment: Your first query where you get the `ids`

Comment: @JohanP i need to start work now, but feel free to write an answer and ill give you an upvote

Comment: No no, your answer is correct, I'm just saying instead of `ToList`, you `ToLookup` your first query, which will turn it essentially into a set so that your second query `Contains` is O(1) and not O(n)

Comment: @JohanP ahh yep i see what your saying

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] StudentsId =( from s in dbcont.Students
                    where s.Active ==true
                    select s.Id).ToArray<int>();

List<CourseTaken> courseTakenList = dbcont.CourseTaken.
                                    Where(c=> StudentsId.Contains(c.S_Id) )
                                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me that you need this query:

```
    from ct in dbcont.CourseTaken
    where ct.CId == courseId
    join s in dbcont.Student.Where(s => s.Active) on ct.S_Id equals s.Id into gsc
    where gsc.Any()
    select ct
```

This is only returning a `CourseTaken` once, regardless of how many active students are taking the course, as long as their is at least one, of course.

Answer (score -1):

```
var result =
    (from C in db.CourseTakens
     join S in db.Students.Where(s => s.Active == true) on C.S_Id equals S.Id
     select C
     ).ToList();
```

This can get only CourseTaken data. You can add Student data to select clause.